# How to programmatically build curves in svg path?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm trying to build a line chart using an SVG, but I'm having a hard time making the path have nice curves. As much as internet told me, the best way to accomplish this is using `Q` and `T`, but I don't really get the intended result.

Here are two of the versions I have built, first one doesn't have curves, but the second one  overflows the svg container for some reason.

```css
*, *:after, *:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

svg {
  width: 30vmin; height: 30vmin;
  fill: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  
  border: 2px solid red;
}

path {
  stroke-width: 3px;
  
  // stroke-dasharray: 4;
}

button {
  left: 0; top: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

html, body {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
  
  background-color: #333ddd;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none"><path d="M0,16.372727272727275 Q7.6923076923076925,29.09090909090908 15.384615384615385,29.09090909090908 23.076923076923077,2.7363636363636346 30.76923076923077,42.73636363636363 38.46153846153846,69.0909090909091 46.15384615384615,56.37272727272727 53.84615384615385,56.37272727272727 61.53846153846154,82.73636363636363 69.23076923076923,95.45454545454545 76.92307692307692,82.73636363636363 84.61538461538461,82.73636363636363 92.3076923076923,42.73636363636363 T100,42.73636363636363" fill="none" stroke="white" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"></path></svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none"><path d="M0,16.372727272727275 Q 7.6923076923076925,29.09090909090908 15.384615384615385,29.09090909090908 T 23.076923076923077,2.7363636363636346 30.76923076923077,42.73636363636363 38.46153846153846,69.0909090909091 46.15384615384615,56.37272727272727 53.84615384615385,56.37272727272727 61.53846153846154,82.73636363636363 69.23076923076923,95.45454545454545 76.92307692307692,82.73636363636363 84.61538461538461,82.73636363636363 92.3076923076923,42.73636363636363 100,42.73636363636363" fill="none" stroke="white" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"></path></svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none"><path d="M0,16.372727272727275 7.6923076923076925,29.09090909090908 15.384615384615385,29.09090909090908 23.076923076923077,2.7363636363636346 30.76923076923077,42.73636363636363 38.46153846153846,69.0909090909091 46.15384615384615,56.37272727272727 53.84615384615385,56.37272727272727 61.53846153846154,82.73636363636363 69.23076923076923,95.45454545454545 76.92307692307692,82.73636363636363 84.61538461538461,82.73636363636363 92.3076923076923,42.73636363636363 100,42.73636363636363" fill="none" stroke="white" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"></path></svg>
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong or how to approach this better?

Comment: How are you calculating the bezier control points?  Did you invent your own method?  Or did you follow one of the many online articles on this topic?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I pretty much invented my own method, I'm just getting x and Y value in percentages and use those as points. Seems like this is fairly wrong way to approach this. If there are two points in a row that have the same Y value then that doesn't even really register.

Could you point me towards a good resource how to calculate bezier points?

Comment: You could try [this page](https://www.particleincell.com/2012/bezier-splines/). Ot [this one](https://medium.com/@ramshandilya/draw-smooth-curves-through-a-set-of-points-in-ios-34f6d73c8f9).  I just found these from a quick google search.

Comment: why dont you try clip path property in css